Is there a free rocky linux monitoring tool?
I am currently looking for a tool to monitor the performance of two Rocky Linux desktop computers. It should monitor aspects such as the CPU, RAM, disk, and network usage (similar to the Windows Task Manager but continuously). The data should be saved for at least a whole year (or ideally forever). Additionally, the data should be visualized to facilitate easy understanding of the current status. It would also be nice if I could receive some warnings (for example, if disk space runs low), but this isn't a must-have feature. Ideally, I could also view the current status of both PCs on my Windows PC. Is there a free tool that can provide this?

You would have found lots if you bothered to do a simple search.

There is GNOME System Monitor (if you are having GNOME DE) similar to Windows Task Manager. But neither it will retain data nor will be accessible from your Windows PC.
So, you will have to go for some Monitoring tool which are used in Industry (by SysAdmins and DevOps for monitoring). Well, there are plenty of Free and Open Source monitoring tools to match your requirements. But, you will have to do some configurations to make them work.
Zabbix is one of my favourite monitoring tool, but it might be overkill for you as you want to monitor just two Linux desktop. Otherwise, it is quite good for saving your performance history logs. It can also send you alerts based on triggers on various channels such as email, slack, SMS, and many other options (you will have to setup).
You can go for this if you have a spare system. Make it as Zabbix server. You will get a web dashboard, which you can access from your Windows PC (or any system) on the same network.
This is how you will get a Dashboard. All your problems will be shown in the Global view Dashboard.

This is how your Linux server's dashboard will look like.

I know Zabbix is going to be overkill for monitoring just two Linux desktop systems, but it can be useful if you are planning to add more systems to be monitored in the future. Not only that, Zabbix can monitor almost everything, your website, network, routers, and a lot more.

Please consider Netdata: https://www.netdata.cloud
It's comprehensive and works well in standalone mode.
